# chef cron tab not working

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to create cron which will run every day morning at 3:15 am with following recipe :

```
if node.roles.include?('cloudera-manager')
  cookbook_file '/usr/local/bin/cloudera-manager-db-backup.sh' do
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode 0755
  action :create
end

cron 'cloudera-manager-db-backup' do
  action :create
  minute '15'
  hour '3'
  user 'root'
  command '/usr/local/bin/cloudera-manager-db-backup.sh'
end
```

cat  cloudera-manager-db-backup.sh.erb

```
#!/bin/bash
# Executes a dump of the postgres database for cloudera manager, gzips the file, upload to s3 and remove file from local machine

<%if node.chef_environment == 'prod'-%>
NAME=$(hostname)
TIME=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`
PGPASSWORD=$(head -1 /var/lib/cloudera-scm-server-db/data/generated_password.txt) pg_dump -p 7432 -U cloudera-scm scm > "/srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql"
gzip "/srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql"
s3cmd put "/srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql.gz" s3://psqlbackup/prod/
rm -rf /srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql.gz

<%elsif node.chef_environment == 'qa'-%>
NAME=$(hostname)
TIME=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`
PGPASSWORD=$(head -1 /var/lib/cloudera-scm-server-db/data/generated_password.txt) pg_dump -p 7432 -U cloudera-scm scm > "/srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql"
gzip "/srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql"
s3cmd put "/srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql.gz" s3://psqlbackup/qa/
rm -rf /srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql.gz

<%elsif node.chef_environment == 'dev'-%>
NAME=$(hostname)
TIME=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`
PGPASSWORD=$(head -1 /var/lib/cloudera-scm-server-db/data/generated_password.txt) pg_dump -p 7432 -U cloudera-scm scm > "/srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql"
gzip "/srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql"
s3cmd put "/srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql.gz" s3://psqlbackup/dev/
rm -rf /srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql.gz
<%end-%>
```

The issue I have is this file (/usr/local/bin/cloudera-manager-db-backup.sh) is created on all environment but with this :

```
<%if node.chef_environment == 'prod'-%>
NAME=$(hostname)
TIME=`date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S`
PGPASSWORD=$(head -1 /var/lib/cloudera-scm-server-db/data/generated_password.txt) pg_dump -p 7432 -U cloudera-scm scm > "/srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql"
gzip "/srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql"
s3cmd put "/srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql.gz" s3://psqlbackup/prod/
rm -rf /srv/${NAME}_${TIME}.psql.gz
```

I want on each env should have separate file as per cloudera-manager-db-backup.sh.erb node.chef_environment

Second issue is even the file is created on all machines but the cron runs on only one machine which is also at wrong time, cron should run at 3:15 am everyday, but it runs at 00:00 (midnight)

Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Any help with why cron is not working at 3:15 am ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `cookbook_file`, but you want a `template`. Cookbook files are dropped "as-is", but Templates are rendered using ERB (the `<%` things):

```rb
if node.roles.include?('cloudera-manager')
  template '/usr/local/bin/cloudera-manager-db-backup.sh' do
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode 0755
    action :create
  end

  # existing code
  cron '...'
end
```

And then move the file from `files/default/cloudera-manager-db-backup.sh` to `templates/default/cloudera-manage-db-backup.sh.erb`.